# Can we save and retrieve contact using mailkit?

Tags: c#, mailkit

I want to save every new contact comes using mail kit, For that, I need a functionality to search in existing contact and save contact in the contact folder.

Is it possible?

Comment: Probably yes, this is the answer for your question.

Comment: If you know than please share some code for it.

Comment: Why? we are not here to do things instead of you. This is the point that I wanted to reach.  **First**: read the [documentation](http://www.mimekit.net/docs/html/Getting-Started.htm). **Second:** figure it out on your own how to do that or search for some tutorials online. Try something and ask on StackOverflow only if you got stuck somewhere. That means that you have to include a [complete and verifiable](https://www.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example of what you tried.

Comment: I had already check but In the documentation, nothing is available about add contact, beyond that I had checked the library if in case any function related to that available but didn't get any, Also googling for it and at the end posted here. Hope somebody has faced this issue who can help here.

Comment: If there isn't anything inside the documentation there are two options: 1) you read it bad. 2) Is not possible to achieve it

Comment: Thanks for informing. I never know if you don't explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MailKit implements *mail* protocols. It does not implement any addressbook protocols.